# Check for all API warnings/errors

Tags: android, android-studio

Is there anyway in Android Studio (maybe using the Analyze -> Inspect Code option?) to check my project for any API warnings or errors? I'm trying to make sure my app is compatible with android back to API 8, and I don't want to manually look through each of my java and res files to check if I don't have to :p.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analyze -> Inspect Code should show you possible API incompatibilities under "Android Lint".

[image: android lint]

Comment: A-ha, I thought it would be in there somewhere, I was looking for API not SDK >.<. I'll accept this answer in 9 minutes when SO lets me :P.